# Spring: Inject a different bean when running tests

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to test my application where I can inject a different bean in the real repository.

I have a repository like this:

```
@Component
public class MyRepo {
   @Autowired
   private MongoTemplate template;

   public void methodA(){
    template.find({});
   }
}
```

That MongoTemplate is read from a configuration file when running the app as a Spring boot.

This is my configuraion:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(){
       MongoTemplate mongo = new MongoTemplate();
       mongo.setxyz;
       return mongo;
    }   
}
```

What I want to achieve is, when running my unit test file, I want to inject below bean into actual MyRepo. In other words, I want Spring to pick up TestConfig.MongoTemplate bean instead of MyConfig.MongoTemplate.

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(){
       MongoTemplate embeded = new MongoTemplate();
       embeded.setxyz;
       return embeded; 
    }   
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Profile("!test")
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(){
   MongoTemplate mongo = new MongoTemplate();
   mongo.setxyz;
   return mongo;
 }   
}
```

for the test config:

```
@Profile(value = {"test"})
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {
@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(){
   MongoTemplate embeded = new MongoTemplate();
   embeded .setxyz;
   return embeded; 
 }   
}
```

in the application.properties file add the following when you want to test.

```
spring.profiles.active=test
```

Another solution can be using the mockito framework [here](https://site.mockito.org)

Comment: ty for the reponse. test will be executed using `gradle test`. I don't think we can use profiles when running tests that way. Can we?

Comment: You can also add on your `@SpringBootTest` test profile with `@ActiveProfiles("test")`

Comment: @Desert: yes you can use profiles for this. this kind of thing is why you have profiles.